# Incorrect normals on generated Cube-mapped (Quad) Sphere

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, geometry, procedural-generation

I've been attempting to generate a sphere programatically by sub-dividing a quad and then transforming it into a sphere. While both the texture coordinates and the positions are correct, the final normals are wrong.

The formula used to calculate the normals per vertex is the standard [v1 - v2] x [v1 - v3] normalised. However, when a shader is used that just outputs normals,the sphere is rendered as pure black. [image: Black sphere with bad normals]

The code used to generate the sphere is shown below, along with a method that dumps the sphere as an obj file. How do I modify this to produce correct normals?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class QuadSphere
{
    int primitiveCountSide;

    VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices;
    ushort[] indices;
    public QuadSphere(int slices)
    {
        int planeVerts = (slices + 1) * (slices + 1);
        vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[planeVerts * 6];
        int planeIndices = slices * slices * 6;
        indices = new ushort[planeIndices * 6];
        primitiveCountSide = planeIndices / 3;
        //Generate planes
        int vertexCount = 0;
        //BOTTOM
        TopBottom(1, slices, vertices, vertexCount);
        vertexCount += planeVerts;
        //TOP
        TopBottom(-1, slices, vertices, vertexCount);
        vertexCount += planeVerts;
        //FRONT
        FrontBack(-1, slices, vertices, vertexCount);
        vertexCount += planeVerts;
        //BACK
        FrontBack(1, slices, vertices, vertexCount);
        vertexCount += planeVerts;
        //LEFT
        LeftRight(-1, slices, vertices, vertexCount);
        vertexCount += planeVerts;
        //RIGHT
        LeftRight(1, slices, vertices, vertexCount);
        vertexCount += planeVerts;
        //Generate indices
        int indexCount = 0;
        int baseVert = 0;
        //BOTTOM
        Indices(2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, slices, ref indexCount, indices, baseVert);
        baseVert += planeVerts;
        //TOP
        Indices(0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, slices, ref indexCount, indices, baseVert);
        baseVert += planeVerts;
        //FRONT
        Indices(2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, slices, ref indexCount, indices, baseVert);
        baseVert += planeVerts;
        //BACK
        Indices(0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, slices, ref indexCount, indices, baseVert);
        baseVert += planeVerts;
        //LEFT
        Indices(2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, slices, ref indexCount, indices, baseVert);
        baseVert += planeVerts;
        //RIGHT
        Indices(0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, slices, ref indexCount, indices, baseVert);
        //Transform Cube to Sphere
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            float x = vertices[i].Position.X;
            float y = vertices[i].Position.Y;
            float z = vertices[i].Position.Z;
            vertices[i].Position = new Vector3(
                (float)(x * Math.Sqrt(1.0 - (y * y / 2.0) - (z * z / 2.0) + (y * y * z * z / 3.0))),
                (float)(y * Math.Sqrt(1.0 - (z * z / 2.0) - (x * x / 2.0) + (z * z * x * x / 3.0))),
                (float)(z * Math.Sqrt(1.0 - (x * x / 2.0) - (y * y / 2.0) + (x * x * y * y / 3.0)))
            );
        }
        //Calculate Normals
        CalculateNormals(vertices, indices);
    }
    void TopBottom(int Y, int slices, VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices, int vertexCount)
    {
        int width = slices + 1, height = slices + 1;
        float advance = (2f / slices);
        float tadvance = (1f / slices);
        for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
        {
            int basev = vertexCount + (z * width);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int index = basev + x;
                vertices[index] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
                    new Vector3(
                        -1 + advance * x,
                        Y,
                        -1 + advance * z
                    ),
                    Vector3.Zero,
                    new Vector2(
                        tadvance * x, 
                        (Y == -1) ? tadvance * z : 1 - (tadvance * z)
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
    void FrontBack(int Z, int slices, VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices, int vertexCount)
    {
        int width = slices + 1, height = slices + 1;
        float advance = (2f / slices);
        float tadvance = (1f / slices);
        for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
        {
            int basev = vertexCount + (z * width);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int index = basev + x;
                vertices[index] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
                    new Vector3(
                        -1 + advance * x,
                        -1 + advance * z,
                        Z
                    ),
                    Vector3.Zero,
                    new Vector2(
                        (Z == -1) ? 1 - (tadvance * x) : tadvance * x, 
                        tadvance * z
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
    void LeftRight(int X, int slices, VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices, int vertexCount)
    {
        int width = slices + 1, height = slices + 1;
        float advance = (2f / slices);
        float tadvance = (1f / slices);
        for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
        {
            int basev = vertexCount + (z * width);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int index = basev + x;
                vertices[index] = new VertexPositionNormalTexture(
                    new Vector3(
                        X,
                        -1 + advance * x,
                        -1 + advance * z
                    ),
                    Vector3.Zero,
                    new Vector2(
                        (X == -1) ? tadvance * z : 1 - (tadvance * z), 
                        tadvance * x
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
    void Indices(ushort t0, ushort t1, ushort t2, ushort t3, ushort t4, ushort t5, int slices, ref int i, ushort[] indices, int baseVert)
    {
        int width = slices + 1;
        int height = slices;
        ushort[] temp = new ushort[6];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            int basev = baseVert + (y * width);
            for (int x = 0; x < slices; x++)
            {
                //Allow defined winding order
                temp[0] = (ushort)(basev + x);
                temp[1] = (ushort)(basev + x + 1);
                temp[2] = (ushort)(basev + width + x);
                temp[3] = (ushort)(basev + width + x + 1);

                indices[i++] = temp[t0];
                indices[i++] = temp[t1];
                indices[i++] = temp[t2];

                indices[i++] = temp[t3];
                indices[i++] = temp[t4];
                indices[i++] = temp[t5];
            }
        }
    }
    public void Dump(string obj)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(obj))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("#quadsphere obj");
            foreach (var vert in vertices)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("v\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", vert.Position.X, vert.Position.Y, vert.Position.Z);
            }
            writer.WriteLine();
            foreach (var vert in vertices)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("vn\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", vert.Normal.X, vert.Normal.Y, vert.Normal.Z);
            }
            writer.WriteLine();
            foreach (var vert in vertices)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("vt\t{0}\t{1}", vert.TextureCoordinate.X, vert.TextureCoordinate.Y);
            }
            writer.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length / 3; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("f\t{0}/{0}/{0}\t{1}/{1}/{1}\t{2}/{2}/{2}", 
                                 1 + indices[i * 3],
                                 1 + indices[i * 3 + 1],
                                 1 + indices[i * 3 + 2]
                                );
            }
        }
    }
    void CalculateNormals(VertexPositionNormalTexture[] array, ushort[] indices)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length / 3; i++)
        {
            var firstVec = array[indices[i * 3]].Position - array[indices[i * 3 + 1]].Position;
            var secondVec = array[indices[i * 3]].Position - array[indices[i * 3 + 2]].Position;
            var normal = Vector3.Cross(firstVec, secondVec);
            normal.Normalize();
            array[indices[i * 3]].Normal += normal;
            array[indices[i * 3 + 1]].Normal += normal;
            array[indices[i * 3 + 2]].Normal += normal;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i].Normal.Normalize();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried to follow your code, but why would you perform calculations to get normals for a sphere? For a sphere, the normal vectors are the same as the positions.

Answer (score 2):

As said by @Reto Koradi, the normals of a sphere are equal to the position.
Therefore the CalculateNormals method can be simplified to the following. No calculation on the individual triangles is necessary.

```
void CalculateNormals(VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        vertices[i].Normal = vertices[i].Position;
}
```